# ion datetime isDateEnabled is not working

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework

ion datetime isDateEnabled is not working. i already added isDateEnabled in HTML, but not working.

here is my code -

```
== HTML ==

<ion-datetime [isDateEnabled]="isDateEnabled('2022-06-26T00:00:00.000Z')"  [firstDayOfWeek]="1" presentation="date" ></ion-datetime>



=== TS file ===
isDateEnabled(dateIsoString: string) {
    const date = new Date(dateIsoString);
    if (getYear(date) === 2022) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have a good day. You need to pass a function in the isDateEnabled property

.html

```
<ion-datetime [isDateEnabled]="isDateEnabled"></ion-datetime>
```

.ts

```
// arrow function allow access global scope
isDateEnabled = (dateIsoString: string): boolean => {
  return true;
};
```

Comment: I change my function to arrow function and I could finally use datePipe/other functions inside. Thanks !